# the method "tableLayout.getTabCounter()" does not show

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[image: this is the code]

what is the problem? why it does not show up this method "tableLayout.getTabCounter()"

i tried this

```
dependencies
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and not post images of code, post the code as correctly formatted text.

But the answer to your question is [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) does not have `Tabs` to count, you have a Typo as you really mean [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout)

Change your call of `tableLayout.getTabCounter()` to `tabLayout.getTabCounter()`

Comment: I'm really thankful for you 

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it has answered your question.